Defining functions beyond exponentiation.
Addition, Multiplication and Exponentiation are well known operations, building up on each other. Multiplication stems from the concept of repeated addition and exponentiation from repeated multiplication. It is only natural to try to extend that idea. Let us define Tetration for positive integer $n$ as repeated exponentiation with $T(1)=a$ and $T(n+1)=a^{T(n)}$ for $a\in \mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$. This recurrence relation can give us values of $T(z)$ for non-negative integers. But how to extend that to all (possible) $z\in\mathbb C$. As it turns out dealing with this function $T$ is very hard because of its extreme growth rate. Let us instead consider the inverse function: the iterated logarithm or superlogarithm. For simplicity we set $a=e$. We obtain the following functional equation: $$F(e^z)=F(z)+1$$ Because we want to get a ''nice'' function $F$, let us assume it has a series expansion given by: $F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$. We get: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ne^{zn}=1+\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mz^m\\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n n^k\frac{z^k}{k!} =1+\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_mz^m$$ Now we obtain a system of infinitely many linear equations: $$ 1=a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+...\\a_1 = a_1 + 2a_2+3a_3+4a_4+...\\ 2a_2 = a_1 + 4a_2+9a_3+16a_4+... \\ 6a_3=a_1+8a_3+27a_3+64a_4+...\\ \dots\\ n!a_n=a_1+2^na_2+3^na_n+4^na_4+...$$ Working backwards from $F(e)=1$ we get $a_0=F(0)=-1$.  How can we continue now? Is there a way to solve that system of equations exactly? If not is there algorithm to compute the values for $a_i$ effectively? The coefficients get very large quite quickly.

note that it is easily seen that $F(e^z)=F(z)+1$ has no solution that is entire since if you start with some large $w$ you can get a chain of at most $C\log |w|$ numbers $w_0,..w_n=w$ with $|w_0| \le M$ with $M$ fixed and $w_k=e^{w_{k-1}}, k=1,..n$ which implies that $|f(w)| \le C_1 \log |w|+C_2, |w| \ge 1$ since $|f(z)| \le K, |z| \le M$ and $f(w)=f(w_0)+k, k \le C \log |w|, |f(w_0)| \le K$; but the Parseval identity on large circles shows that  $|f(w)| \le C_1 \log |w|+C_2, |w| \ge 1$ implies that all the Taylor coefficients except $a_0$ vanish etc

I'm used to look at this (and alike) questions from the view at diagonalization of matrices (mostly Carleman matrices). I'm a bit insure when I try to put your equation into such a system. The rhs-coefficients at the $a_k$ variables can be put into a simple (Vandermonde) matrix, I call it "VZ" and the vectors of $a_k$ seem then to form eigenvectors of that matrix "VZ" - but what about the missing $a_0$ variable? I would like to make it precisely a matrix' eigenvector equation (of course infinite size) and discuss then as diagonalization. (... cntd)

(... cntd) For the $z\to e^z−1$ problem this gives Schroeder's equations which are equivalent to solving a diagonalization of/into (infinite) triangular matrices. But for the $z \to e^z$-problem here the diagonalization-attempt has not yet been solved, and before stepping more into this (again, in my case) I'd like to make it sure, that your ansatz does really fit that (Carleman) matrix-approach. (And thus whether my research/partial results fits your requirements at all ... )

In complement to Gottfried Helms's comment, it is to be noted that your functional equation is the Abel equation for the exponential function $-$ which is equivalent to Schroeder's equation through a change of variable $-$, which is linked to the well-known problem of the functional square root / half-iterate of exponential, whose solution itself is known to have no closed form and be even non-unique.

You might see at the attempt of Peter Walker in "indefinitely differentiable ... functions...." in "math of computation" Vol 57, Number 196 ,1991 Skip the first part and look at chapter 4 where he discusses a "matrix-method". This looks much like what you discuss here. (The Walker's paper is available on JSTOR) His attempted/provisorical solution is numerical and results from increasing matrixsize and assumption of convergence of the found coefficients. (But a proof for actual convergence for infinite matrixsize is admittedly not given)

No complete solution for the whole infinite system is known to me. By our "tetration-forum" I came across that attempt 2007 by some amateur (Andrew Robbins), but we found later that Peter Walker had tried this ansatz already in the 1980ies.
Robbins'/Walker's attempt was due to nonexistence of a full solution  to approximate a solution by increasing the size of the equation system; Robbins started with an N=4 ansatz, increased up to the N=16 system (or so), Peter Walker documented solutions up to N=80 (where I found that with the "double-precision" with which they likely could do the computer-calculations then he had an error and a 200-digits internal precision I got a better result from the 10'th or so digit). A friend in the "tetration-forum" extended the computation up to N=700, and the found sets of coefficients really seemed to converge to something (for an example for the coefficient $a_1$ see
the screenshot of Peter Walker's article below).

Screenshot Peter Walker's "matrix method", in chap.4:

(from "indefinitely differentiable ... functions...." in "math of computation" Vol 57, Number 196 ,1991)

The key idea for this attempts was to ignore the $a_0$ coefficients and do matrix-solving for a submatrix, where the empty first column was ignored and submatrix of size NxN was taken from beside.
I've recalculated the solutions for some size N just for this anwer here and got for the first few coefficients the following (improving!) approximations:
          a1              a2             a3                    a4               a5               a6
N=6  0.917524645460  0.247754234864  -0.121814756867      -0.0949589083439  0.0591972750747  -0.00770249018748   
N=10 0.916132450356  0.248864100555  -0.111836422393      -0.0931585983368  0.0139505408922    0.0368895758136
N=16 0.915958619892  0.249218563581  -0.110611477420      -0.0935821868946  0.0105881557811    0.0356292063641 
N=30 0.915943739177  0.249335338220  -0.110461809104      -0.0938709873750  0.0100411210753    0.0358040039088

But, as Peter Walker already mentioned: this is by no means a valid solution, even if the coefficients taken from a NxN-system with N going to infinity seem to converge to a set of values, then still the results computed with that coefficients converge to a different value from that which he computed by another method (and, as I have tested later, as well from the results taken by an implementation of the Kneser-ansatz.)
So, in short, I do not know of any valid solution based on this ansatz alone.

btw. I'm composing an explicite description for the matrix scheme in a "sandbox": https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16602/1714 .It's only a scribble so far and will be deleted soon; if I get this finished I'll put it in a small essay available on my homepage. 
